# Syncfusion ej2-angular-calendars package need to be mapped in systemjs.config.js but this file doesn't exists anymore in Angular-cli

Tags: angular, datepicker, systemjs, syncfusion

I'm trying to create a datePicker component from Syncfusion in a project I'm working on. 
The problem is that Syncfusion ej2-angular-calendars package need to be mapped in systemjs.config.js configuration file that doesn't exists anymore in Angular-cli. (I'm using Angular 7 and SYNCFUSION EJ2)

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you are using Angular CLI project, there is no need to map the ej2-angular-calendars package in the systemjs.config.js file. This is only applicable for the angular application using systemjs configuration. 
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9968/how-to-create-an-angular-7-datepicker-component

To know more about component rendering using angular CLI please refer the below documentation link.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/getting-started/angular-cli/

To know more about DatePicker component, please refer the below getting started documentation link.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/datepicker/getting-started/?no-cache=1#setting-the-selected-date

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of mapping packages in system.js.config file while creating project using Angular CLI.

Checkout the below link for

KB link: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9968/how-to-create-an-angular-7-datepicker-component

GitHub sample for DatePicker rendering using Angular CLI configuration is attached in the above knowledge base document.